# ANT build.xml on Sublime Text

Tags: macos, ant, sublimetext2

The guys I'm working with use Eclipse as their IDE and I'm using Sublime. Don't really want to ditch it because it works well.

They have a build script at the root of their project under a build dir which contains the build.xml file.

Sublime is clearly looking at my project root for build.xml but failing, how do I change where it's looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either change the default Ant.sublime-build or make a copy of it and set the new file as your default "Build system".  You can change "working_dir" or change cmd to something like

"cmd": ["ant", "-f", "/path_to/build.xml"]

or both.

On OSX it's in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Java